# How to write C# to call vb6 code?

Tags: c#, vb6

I have an activeX DLL in VB6 , and i've been asked to run some tests with it. since i dont have VB6 environment anymore, i thought it'll be best to try and make a simple C# program that will call the registered COM Dll. to do that i copied the DLL into c:\windows\system32, used regsrv32 to register the DLL, restarted the computer and this DLL is added to COM so I added it to my project and referenced to it from my project. I created an object from it and tried to invoke a function from that but there is nothing available but DllUnusedClass and DllUnused.

Comment: You could try using a decompiler to find what classes are available.

Comment: You don't need to use a decompiler. Use something like the Ole type library viewer that comes with the Windows SDK

Comment: the available things is an interface called DllUnused and a class, NNetApply, i know it has a funtion and i wanna invoke it, but i don't know how!

Answer (score 2):

You say you've added a reference to the COM dll to your project, now I would right click on the reference and select "View in object browser". This will show you which types are available in the referenced dll.

It may be you're not creating the appropriate type of object, so viewing it in object browser should help you decide which type of object to create.

Comment: oh, thanck you John. There is another problem! the dll added to my references is NNetApply but the one is shown in object browser is Iterop.NNetApply, and i already cannot use it 'cause my program doesn't know it! You know, I can add NNetApply on the top of my project but it doesn't know the Interop.NNetApply namespase;

Comment: Interop.NNetApply is an automatically generated assembly that Visual Studio has created, to communicate between managed and native code. It should contain managed definitions of the same types defined in the COM library

Comment: So this namespace contains just one type (NNetApply) and is has a interface called DllUnused and a class, NNetApply.DllUnusedClass?! i know it has a function, so how can i invoke that function?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that any class you have in the VB6 project, that you want to access from your .Net application, has the `Instancing` property set to `6 - GlobalMultiUse` so that it is in scope.

I have tested your scenario with the `Instancing` property set to the default `5 - MultiUse` and experienced the same issue you described.